# Algorithm or Code for creating array, rule is as specified?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, python-2.7

I want to create 2D array as below:

For Example:

```
For level 3:


         7            => Array[2]

   3          6       => Array[1]

1     2     4     5   => Array[0]


i.e. Array = [[1,2,4,5], [3,6], [7]]
```

.

```
For level 4:

                    15                          => Array[3]

         7                      14              => Array[2]

   3          6           10           13       => Array[1]

1     2     4     5    8     9     11     12    => Array[0]


i.e. Array = [[1,2,4,5,8,9,11,12], [3,6,10,13], [7,14], [15]]
```

What I need is a function taking number of level as argument returning Array as mentioned above.

i.e:

```
def function(level):
    ''' ..........................


    ...........................'''
    return Array
```

Comment: i think the question is a bit unclear, I didnt understand what you mean by associating an 2D array to a Binary Tree

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry. The rule for filling array is like perfect binary tree, So, I think its easy to understand.

Comment: Let us see you really tried something yourself.

Comment: Thank You all... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data structure is recursive, so it's natural to use a recursive function to produce it.

The root node of the tree of depth `depth` is `n = 2 ** depth - 1`; it's more efficient to calculate that using bit shifting. The left subtree has a root node of `n // 2`, the right subtree is identical except that `n // 2` is added to all its nodes.

Here's a recursive generator that produces the desired list.

```
def btree(depth):
    if depth < 1:
        return

    n = (1 << depth) - 1
    yield [n]

    a = n // 2
    for seq in btree(depth - 1):
        yield seq + [u + a for u in seq]

lst = list(btree(4))[::-1]
print(lst)
```

**output**

```
[[1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 11, 12], [3, 6, 10, 13], [7, 14], [15]]
```

---

If you want to print the tree rows in top-down order, you can just do this:

```
for row in btree(5):
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
[31]
[15, 30]
[7, 14, 22, 29]
[3, 6, 10, 13, 18, 21, 25, 28]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 11, 12, 16, 17, 19, 20, 23, 24, 26, 27]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I want.

Comment: ohh... Yeah, I didn't know about that. Thank You again for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Here is the last row of numbers

```
def last_row(level):
    m = 2 ** (level - 1)
    L = [0 for i in range(m)]
    L[0] = 1
    k = 1
    while k < m:
        incr = 2 * k - 1
        for i in range(k):
            L[k+i] = L[i] + incr
        k = incr + 1
    return L
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another recursive solution that I figured. The left sub-tree value is floor(current value) and the right sub-tree value is (current value -1).
I pre-calculate the necessary powers of 2, but the draw-back is my passing of additional arguments (lists): In any case, hopefully this will be helpful for clarity when building a solution.

```
def driver(level):
    if level <= 0:
        return None
    # initialize the list to have (level) columns
    lst = [[] for i in range(level)]
    # pre-calculate the necessary powers of 2
    powers = [1]
    for i in range(1, level+1):
        powers.append(powers[i-1] << 1)

    # call the main calculation function
    calc(level, powers[level]-1, lst, powers)

    return lst

def calc(level, val, lst, powers):
    # add the value in pre-order
    lst[level-1].append(val)
    # base case, level is 1,
    # do not make additional recursive calls here
    if level > 1:
        # calculate values in the left sub-tree
        calc(level-1, val - powers[level-1], lst, powers)
        # calculate values in the right sub-tree
        calc(level-1, val-1, lst, powers)

print(driver(4))
```